# Grid layout display is not correct

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to build a simple Android app.
on emulator the grid displays the buttons perfectly , but when installing the app to my mobile the grid looks horrible.
Below is the XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.modysoft.gridlayoutdemo.MainActivity">

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:text="Good Morning"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:onClick="Buttontapped"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"

        android:id="@+id/goodmorning" />

    <Button
        android:text="Good Evening"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:onClick="Buttontapped"
        android:id="@+id/goodevening" />

    <Button
        android:text="HI / Bye"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:onClick="Buttontapped"
        android:id="@+id/hibye" />

    <Button
        android:text="Good Bye"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:onClick="Buttontapped"
        android:id="@+id/goodbye" />

    <Button
        android:text="Please"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:onClick="Buttontapped"
        android:id="@+id/please" />

    <Button
        android:text="Thank You &#10; Very Much"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:onClick="Buttontapped"
        android:id="@+id/thankyou" />

    <Button
        android:text="Welcome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:onClick="Buttontapped"
        android:id="@+id/welcome" />

    <Button
        android:text="How are you?"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:onClick="Buttontapped"
        android:id="@+id/howareyou" />

</GridLayout>
```

[this how shown in mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zn0rQ.png)

[this how shown in emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRhWZ.png)

Comment: give  more details...about your device??

Comment: Try to replace the `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to `android:layout_height="0dp"` to all the `button` in the column

Comment: it's become worse

Comment: `android:layout_columnWeight="1"` and `android:layout_rowWeight="1"` requires API level 21 and higher.  Your Samsung Note 3 is lower than API 21. That is why you are seeing the layouts not proper without `android:layout_columnWeight="1"` and `android:layout_rowWeight="1"`

Comment: So what should i do to get the same design after removing these tags ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the same what you expect without using `<GridLayout>`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
        <Button
            android:text="Good Morning"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:onClick="Buttontapped"
            android:id="@+id/goodmorning" />
        <Button
            android:text="Good Evening"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:onClick="Buttontapped"
            android:id="@+id/goodevening" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
        <Button
            android:text="Good Bye"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:onClick="Buttontapped"
            android:id="@+id/goodbye" />
        <Button
            android:text="HI / Bye"
            android:id="@+id/hibye"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:onClick="Buttontapped"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
        <Button
            android:text="Please"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:onClick="Buttontapped"
            android:id="@+id/please" />
        <Button
            android:text="Thank You &#10; Very Much"
            android:id="@+id/thankyou"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:onClick="Buttontapped"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

        <Button
            android:text="Welcome"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:onClick="Buttontapped"
            android:id="@+id/welcome" />
        <Button
            android:text="How are you?"
            android:id="@+id/howareyou"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:onClick="Buttontapped"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Worked Perfectly , Thank you

Comment: i already did but... Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.